# Retornar todas as correspondências no excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Olá, pessoal!

Estou desenvolvendo uma tabela que retorne as atividades realizadas por cada colaborador da minha empresa. A tabela de referência é a seguinte:

[image: Tabela contendo todas as atividades atribuídas aos seus respectivos colaboradores]

Com base nessa tabela, estou desenvolvendo tabelas individuais para cada colaborador, das quais devem mostrar as atividades que o mesmo exerce, conforme exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para isso, estou utilizando a seguinte fórmula:

```
=SE(LINS($1:1)>CONT.SE($M$2:$M$70;$S$2);"";ÍNDICE($H$2:$H$70;MENOR(SE($M$2:$M$70=$S$2;LIN($M$2:$M$70)-LIN($M$2)+1;FALSO);LINS($1:1))))
```

Essa fórmula está funcionando parcialmente. O único problema é que ela não está retornando as atividades que o colaborador exerce em conjunto com outros. Ou seja, ela não retorna atividades que possuem mais de um colaborador atribuído.

Tentei substituir esse trecho da função:

```
SE($M$2:$M$70=$S$2;
```

PARA:

```
SE($M$2:$M$70=ÉTEXTO($S$2);
```

Mas não está dando certo. Vocês teriam alguma outra solução? Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Olá!

Uma alteração na fórmula que pode ajudar é verificar se a célula contém o texto procurado, da seguinte maneira:

```
=SE(ÉNÚM(LOCALIZAR("Texto Procurado";A3));"OK";"Não OK")
```

Sendo que `A3` seria a referência da célula em que o texto está sendo procurado.

Espero que ajude!